# HTML debug pretty-printing for Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pretty-print

After using the excellent [Krumo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/krumo/) package for PHP (perhaps most famous for its use in [Drupal](https://drupal.org/project/devel)), I was wondering if there is something similar for Python.

Specifically, I'm looking for a package that does the following: turns arbitrary (or almost arbitrary) Python variables into themed HTML/CSS. Javascript component to collapse the various elements is preferred, but easy enough to write myself if necessary.

Is such a module available? I'd prefer something standalone, but if this only exists as part of another web framework, it would still be a good starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I was unable to find any existing libraries, I wrote [Pymo](https://github.com/threewestwinds/Pymo). It functions very similarly to Krumo, rendering any Python variable into html which can be printed or saved to a file for viewing in a web browser, with javascript and CSS to make it readable.

Please take a look at it and submit bug reports or feature requests if it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [cgitb](http://docs.python.org/library/cgitb.html) is what your looking for:

> The cgitb module provides a special exception handler for Python
>   scripts. (Its name is a bit misleading. It was originally designed to
>   display extensive traceback information in HTML for CGI scripts. It
>   was later generalized to also display this information in plain text.)
>   After this module is activated, if an uncaught exception occurs, a
>   detailed, formatted report will be displayed. The report includes a
>   traceback showing excerpts of the source code for each level, as well
>   as the values of the arguments and local variables to currently
>   running functions, to help you debug the problem. Optionally, you can
>   save this information to a file instead of sending it to the browser.

Comment: I hadn't seen that module before - thanks for the pointer. But it doesn't do what I'm looking for. I want to print variables, rather than tracebacks - think "pickle into HTML".